# Running Angular test from IntelliJ (karma) adds invisible breakpoints before each test?

Tags: angular, debugging, intellij-idea, karma-runner

I was used to debug test in my Angular project directly from Intellij.

Running them directly with the small green arrow using 'run' works fine. But when I switch to 'debug' it stops before each test (and there are many).

The config:

[image]

The console shows 'instantiating tests' and in the debug window I get the 'green arrow', which makes it look like it has stopped on a breakpoint.

[image]

However, I don't have any breakpoints enabled:

[image]
What can I do to debug/fix this? I probably have a wrong setting somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be [WEB-59923](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-59923/Instantiating-tests...-Debugging-Angular-tests-not-possible) that is fixed in 2023.1.1 update (not yet available:()

Comment: It seems not fixed yet. As workaround, downgrading chrome < 111 worked for me :)